# Display an alert message when a violation constraint occurs

Tags: javascript, ajax, jakarta-ee

Good evening,

I show you my interface so that you understand better:

[add place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1F5bu.png)

I add a unique constraint on 2 columns (local_name and number_place) everything works perfectly, there is just a small problem that I want to add a local name with a place number that already exists it brings me back into a blank page like this:

[White page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZdPW.png)

and it shows me the error on NetBeans that I violated the constraint ... whereas I would like it not to redirect me to the blank page but it stays on the same page and that it shows me a message of type:

> Error you entered two premises with the same place number and the same name of local

I tried a little javascript code and ajax but it does not work here is the code I added in my servlet jee:

```
if("ajouter".equals(action)){
PreparedStatement st1=c.prepareStatement("insert into place values (null,?,?,?,?)");
st1.setString(1, nom_local);
st1.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(numeroplace));
st1.setString(3, prixplace);
st1.setString(4, tailleplace);
int resadd=st1.executeUpdate();
if (resadd>0){
request.setAttribute("msg", "place ajouté avec succés !");

}
else {
request.setAttribute("msg", "place non ajouté !");
throw new Exception("Erreur vous avez entrez deux locaux ayant le meme numéro de place et le meme nom de local" );
}
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/Place_locaux.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

and here is the javascript code:

```
<script>

jQuery.ajax({
type: POST,
url: Place_locaux.java,
success: function (response) {
//Code en cas de succès de l'appel
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert(chr.responseText); //Ce code affichera le message d'erreur.
}
});
</script>
```

I hope I have been clear and I look forward to your response, and I want to thank you for your reply in advance

Comment: Bienvenue sur Stackoverflow ! It looks like you are never catching your exception, so it just stop the execution of your Java rather than returning an error to the frontend.

Comment: thanks a lot i'm new on stackoverflow haha.
thank you for your answer but I still do not understand how can I make my exception  detected? and how can I display the alert message that indicates the error?

Comment: You need a global catch that will transform your exception into error response with an error code ( like 400 ). This way, when your code throws an error, it will be sent back to the frontend as an error and your alert will be shown.

Comment: I understand what you mean but I do not know how to do it in code can you explain to me with code please?

Comment: I am always in the same problem please help me !!! :(

Comment: I don't know what to explain more. You need a global `try {} catch(Exception ex) {}` that handles all your exception and then send them as error to your frontend, by responding to your http request. If you're not sure, google it in the language you are using.

Comment: j'ai déjà un try catch global voici le code que j'ai mis dans le catch : catch(Exception ex){
          request.setAttribute("msg", "error !");
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }  mais ça ne fonctionne toujours pas !